# Create HMAC_256 from a string in Golang

Tags: go, cryptography, hmac

I am trying to generate a HMAC 256 hash from a message and secret. However when I return it, it is not correct.

```
func makeSig(s Signature) string {
    secretHash := md5.New()
    secretHash.Write([]byte("secret"))
    key := secretHash.Sum(nil)
    fmt.Println("The secret key is ", hex.EncodeToString(key))

    message := strings.Join([]string{"one", "two", "three"}, "")
    fmt.Println("The message is ", message)

    sig := hmac.New(sha256.New, key)
    sig.Write([]byte(message))
    return hex.EncodeToString(sig.Sum(nil))
}
```

I'm not sure what's wrong, please advise.

Comment: You haven't shown us what this code must correspond to. How was the MAC created that you compare the result to?

Comment: I've just been comparing it manually to using this in ruby:

`hash  = OpenSSL::HMAC.hexdigest("sha256", key, message)`

Comment: OK, this is a simple hmac-sha256. Why do you additionally run MD5 on the "key" in your go code? Don't do that if you want hmac-sha256.

Comment: I want to hash the secret before using it as the key. So I throw it through MD5 first.

Comment: OK, but then it can't match with the result of the code that you posted in the comments. Why do you expect the same results if you use different methods?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You're printing out the hex encoded version of your "key", but you're using the raw, unencoded bytes for that key.

Your key in the example is printed as:

```
5ebe2294ecd0e0f08eab7690d2a6ee69
```

but you're giving this to the hmac:

```
[]byte{0x5e, 0xbe, 0x22, 0x94, 0xec, 0xd0, 0xe0, 0xf0, 0x8e, 0xab, 0x76, 0x90, 0xd2, 0xa6, 0xee, 0x69}
```

which as a string, looks like:

```
"^\xbe"\x94\xec\xd0\xe0\xf0\x8e\xabv\x90\xd2\xa6\xeei"
```

Using the strings directly should show the difference: http://play.golang.org/p/wteqLNcnTV

Which prints

```
3f0ee534c3d86cb16f4413fe1a76a12f94449f751f7d632cd87f24b94e76c710
```

Comment: But in the [godocs](https://golang.org/pkg/crypto/hmac/#New) it says that hmac.New takes a []byte key? What should I pass it?

Comment: So it should be: `key := hex.EncodeToString(secretHash.Sum(nil))`

Comment: @SebastianJ: yes, if you want to match whatever the ruby code you're using does, that's one way to do it. Note that you're not gaining any entropy by hex-encoding the digest (you just make it longer with a smaller value range)

Comment: this is old, but import to note for Googlers.. in Go, []byte (or a slice of type byte) is how strings are represented. So they're interchangeable using the functions `string(slice-of-bytes-here)` or `[]byte(string-goes-here)`

Comment: @SamiFoua: the types are not interchangeable, and strings are not represented by a byte slice, but they can be converted which is explained in the docs here https://golang.org/ref/spec#Conversions_to_and_from_a_string_type

Comment: I'm talking practical use. the process of converting them is what I mean by interchangeable. of course technically speaking, under the hood how Go implements them is another story. Better example of what I mean: https://play.golang.org/p/Jti97enncSf